# Cannot use pictureBox.Image in my class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am making a game and I have a class called `gameScripts`. Inside `gameScripts` is a `public void` method called `paintSquare`. When this method is called,the method uses 2 `if` statements,and depending on which one is true,the squares image will be changed accordingly.

The problem is,when I try to use `pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile("cross.png");` to change the picture to a cross,`pictureBox.Image` gets a red line under it with the error message "`Error  2   'System.Windows.Forms.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Image' and no extension method 'Image' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\gameScripts.cs`"

I have tried including System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms in my namespaces,but I still get this error.

Any help would be appreciated,thanks.

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand? You want a `PictureBox`, not a `Control`.

Comment: Well generally if I wanted to change an image in my code,I would use Image.FromFile("Image.png") to change the image,but in this case,an error message has occured

Comment: What is `pictureBox`? How you declare and assign it a value?

Comment: pictureBox is a parameter that the paintSquare function takes,and it is a control.

Comment: @ReubenWard: Why do you think `Control` has an `Image` property?

Comment: As the underline is trying to tell you, your error has nothing to do with `Image.FromFile`.

Comment: Do I need to specify the type of Control being used so that c# will recognize that I am using a control with an `Image` property?       Edit: I see,I need to use pictureBox instead of Control,didnt realize,thank you :)

Comment: please post the signature of your paintSquare method..

Answer (score 0):

The message `'ClassXXX' does not contain a definition for 'YYY' and no extension method 'YYY' accepting a first argument of type 'ClassXXX' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` means literally what it says. Most likely in you code there is construction like this:

```
myObject.YYY
```

but the class, the instance of which the myObject is, does not have a member with name YYY.

For example:

```
class MyClass {
     public string MyField;
}

...

var myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.MyField = "OK";
myObj.NotMyField = "FAIL"; // compiler will complain at this line
```

However, the compiler gets the list of available properties and methods by looking at the variable type. This may lead to the situation when the object itself have the member but compiler cannot see it as the variable is defined with a different type.

Consider the following code fragment:

```
class MyExtClass : MyClass {
     public string MyNewField;
}

...

MyClass myObj = new MyExtClass();
myObj.MyField = "OK";
myObj.MyNewField = "FAIL"; // compiler will complain at this line
                           // because MyClass does not have it
```

So in your code the `pictureBox` is seems to be defined as `System.Windows.Forms.Control`. So even if it is, in fact, `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox`, compiler cannot know it and stops with the error.